# Android Parallax Animation

Tags: animation, android-3.0-honeycomb, android, parallax

Requirements: Honeycomb 3.1, Galaxy Tab 10.1

I'm working on a project that requires Parallax animation in the transition from one element to another, the elements are in a component similar to the Gallery and what I need is when the user swipes over the screen to navigate to the different groups, the elements on these groups are animated with a parallax approach.

I have tested with the basic animation approach animating the bitmaps but it's slow so currently I am testing with SurfaceView.

What do you think is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23308111/2382964

Answer (score 0):

If you try JetBoy which comes with Android SDK, you can see the quality of a paralax bitmap scrolling on SurfaceView. I find that smooth scrolling of huge sprites and background looks of course smoother with openGL.