# Android Parallax - offsetPixel

Tags: android, parallax

I am trying to design a complicated parallaxing animation that resides inside a ViewPager. The animation uses onPageScrolled function's offsetPixel to calculate the position of the images.
However this approach is causing a lot of problems due to the offsetPixel if scrolled fast can skip (ex: 1 to 123 to 250 to 251) and when slow it's too sensitive so the animation seems jittery.

Is there a better way to calculate the position of the screen besides offsetPixels. If so, can anyone please help me figure it out. Would appreciate it very much!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know exactly if one of the pages has to have the parallax effect, or it has to been a parallax effect between de transition of changing pages.

I developed a small library to make the second one, https://github.com/xgc1986/ParallaxPagerLibrary

Demo: [parallax demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zEOUWY9Hvo)

This library work with Views, the you can use it with imageViews to have the effect.

To do that I don't use de onPageScrolled function, basically then you don't permit to the developer to use this listener anymore, the to solve that I implemented a child of PageTransformer